# What was character of Chmielnitski's rise?

Tags: russia, 17th-century, poland, ukraine

What was the character of Chmielnitski's rise? It has started as a private conflict between him and a polish nobel, Aleksander Czapliński. But what was after? And what was the reason to fight when Chmielnitski ruled all the Ukraine?

Comment: Who?  It is very useful to link proper nouns to some source for those of us who aren't immediately familiar with the individual. H:SE should be a learning resource for all of us, not just for the person asking the question.  It would also be useful to summarize the conflict a bit more clearly than you've done here.

Comment: Please modify your question to include the clarifications in your comments on the answer.  The goal is to create a Q&A that is of general reference use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bogdan Khmelnytsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohdan_Khmelnytsky) was arguably the ["William Wallace"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Wallace) of the Ukraine. He not only took on the one noble, but the whole Polish noble "Establishment," to the point where even the King of Poland (a personal friend), wouldn't defend him.

So he basically started a war between his Cossacks and the Poles. He was initially successful but the Poles were unforgiving; they wanted his head and continued the war, which started to turn in their favor. This drove him and Ukraine into the arms of Russia, and helped set the stage for Poland's decline and Russia's rise.

Comment: It's a very useful answer but the question was about the character after the first phase of the rise.

Comment: @enedil:The sequence of events is something like the following. 1) He got into a fight with the one noble. 2) the other Polish nobles supported the first noble. 3) He incited the Cossacks against the Polish nobles and started a war. 4) He won early, and started to lose. 5) He tried to recoup his losses by allying with Russia ("out of the frying pan into a fire"). The "character of the rising is that a private quarrel "morphed" into a multinational war.